# Integral Calculus Drained Tank

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Is my answer to the question below correct??

[image]

i) 
$$\frac{dv}{dt} = 2t - 20 \Rightarrow V = 2 (\frac {t^2}{1} = dt $$
$$ V(t) = t^2 - 20t + c \Rightarrow V(5) = 0 \Rightarrow$$
$$25 - 100 + c = 0 \Rightarrow c = 100-25 = 75 \Rightarrow c = 75$$
$$t = 0 \Rightarrow V(t) = 75$$
$$t=1 \Rightarrow V(1) = t^2 - 20t + 75$$

ii)
$$V(4) = 16 - 80 + 75 = 11 Kilolitres$$

Is this correct? If not can anyone help??

Comment: Please also edit the first line in your equation.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question appears to be correct. However, I understand the second question differently. The fourth minute does only last from 3:00 minutes to 4:00 minutes. Compare to how the first minute lasts from 0:00 to 1:00. You calculated the volume of the drained oil from 0:00 to 4:00. The question to that answer would be "How much oil is drained in the first four minutes".

Now that you know how much oil has been drained in the first four minutes, simply substract the oil that has been drained in the first three minutes, i.e. $$\int \limits_3^4 \frac{dv}{dt}dt$$

Comment: So $$V(3) - V(4)$$

Comment: No, the other way around, upper boundary minus lower boundary: $V(4) - V(3)$. Think about it: $V(4)$ gives you all the oil drained in the first 4 minutes, and $V(3)$ in the first three minutes. Thus, $V(4)-V(3)$ is exactly what was drained in between.

Comment: Could you help me out with this please? Is it $$V(4) - V(3) = t^2 - 20t + 75 $$ Not sure what to do after this.

Comment: Read $V(4)$ as $V(t=4)$ and $V(3)$ as $V(t=3)$. Substitute $t$ for 3 or 4 respectively and finally substract $V(3)$ from $V(4)$.

Comment: Can anyone else help me with this?? As I am really stuck. I'm so close to completing it. Just need a little help.

Comment: What is unclear?

Comment: Where I have gone wrong, and how to do it correctly.

Comment: I just explained it to you, what didn't you understand? :)

Comment: I know you did. I understand you need to subtract $$V(3) $$ From $$V(4)$$ But I don't know how to do this. I'm just stuck on how to write it out. Would you be able to show me?

Comment: If $V(t) = t^2 - 20 t + 75$ then this is the formula for any point $t$ in time. If you want to know what the volume $V$ is for a specific point, let's say $t=3$ then you just replace all the $t$'s with $3$'s. Same for $V(4)$. If you are unsure, please post what you think you have to do in order to calculate V(4) and V(3).

Comment: $$V(3) = 3^2 - 20 x 3 + 75$$ $$V(3) = 9 - 60 + 75$$ $$V(3) = 24$$ Kilolitres. Then I work out V(4) Then subtract which will give me the amount during the forth minute.